# DynamoDB Single Table Design: How to get all entities of a type

Tags: amazon-web-services, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

I am on the way creating a Single Table DynamoDB Design for relevant entities in my application. I mainly borrowed ideas from here:
https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-dynamodb-design-patterns/blob/master/data-models/an-online-shop/AnOnlineShop.md

While most of the things are clear to me, one simple thing is missing for me. How can i query all entities of a certain type? See the image below for the schema.

[image]

As you can see, the main entity records have PK and SK with the same values. SK only changes when you want to have 1:N relations to other entities, as seen in the entityType warehouseItem.

My main question is: How do i get all users (fast without scan of course)?

What i learned is that i can't do a begins_with on a PartitionKey. Of course i could think of doing records like this:

```
PK       SK
users   u#logemann
users   u#smith
```

But this would require additional data entries and would be kind of duplicates to my main user records seen above. Or is it possible to create a GSI with a constant value of "users" for PK and the value of SK for SK?

Whats the best way to solve this?

Answer (score 13):

I think the easiest way is to add "EntityType" in a GSI as PartitionKey and "PK" as SortKey. This way i have all my entities queryable in a performant way.

Comment: Correct!  This is the DynamoDB way to solve this problem.

Comment: @SethGeoghegan wouldn't this potentially be an issue if you have a large dataset, because the GSI would have a potentially enormous number of documents in a single partition key? edit: For example, in the OPs question `user` is a type, if there are 100k users then the `user` GSI partition key would be potentially very large? Or is that not a concern?

Comment: "Storage is cheap." 

Rick Houlihan (DynamoDB GOAT) offers this solution as well.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xfxBhvGpoa0
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KYy8X8t4MB8&ab_channel=ServerlessLand

Comment: @shoelessone, when DDB creates partitions it's based on PK + SK. Therefore size won't be an issue since 10GB partitions will be created for your 100k users. However, you need to be aware of partition throughput limits: 3000 RCUs and 1000 WCUs. See more [here](https://www.alexdebrie.com/posts/dynamodb-limits/#partition-throughput-limits).

Answer (score 0):

You can have one GSI and then overload it.
You can get more information from : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-gsi-overloading.html

Comment: Can you add relevant sections from this link in the answer? that way, if the link goes down, we still have enough information to help the commuity